# In resource owner password flow, can user handle the scope?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, access-token, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 for authenticate user from a single application page. For the need of the project, I have to use the resource owner password flow.
Identity Server and my application work fine together. Identity Server give an Access Token and I can use this token to access some API that we own.
However, I was asking myself about the Access Token, users and socpes. For now my setup is this one.

- I have an API that require the scope API-1.
- I have a client (my SPA) where I defined the scope API-1
- And I have a user.

In this configuration, it is the client who own the right to access the API, not the user. And I'm wondering how to give this scope to the user and not anymore to the client.

Stupidly, I'm wondering if user can own the scope and not the client. Maybe I've miss or misunderstood something, so please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Resource Owner Password Flow your client will always need to have permission to the scope that your resource is protected by.  This does not mean that you cannot protect your API based on claims related to the user however.

If in your API for example you need different permissions based on the user accessing the API look to use the claims information as part of your authorization.  In the Resource Owner Password Flow example at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html you will see that it mentions this at the foot of the page, see the two paragraphs as follows:

> When you send the token to the identity API endpoint, you will notice one small but important difference compared to the client credentials grant. The access token will now contain a sub claim which uniquely identifies the user. This “sub” claim can be seen by examining the content variable after the call to the API and also will be displayed on the screen by the console application.
>
> The presence (or absence) of the sub claim let’s the API distinguish between calls on behalf of clients and calls on behalf of users.

Comment: So, I can add to my user some scope who represent API. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: You don't add scopes to the users, you add claims to the users, the scope remains with your client.  In your API you can then access these user claims and even use them as part of Authorization if you want to do so, this could be done by adding a policy to the Authorize attribute on your controller or action.  More information, including examples, on Claims Based Authorzation in asp.net core can be seen at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims